# SmartPointer : cast between base and derived classes

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting, smart-pointers

Say you have a function like this :

```
SmartPtr<A> doSomething(SmartPtr<A> a);
```

And classes like this :

```
class A { }
class B : public A { }
```

And now I do this :

```
SmartPtr<A> foo = new B();
doSomething(foo);
```

Now, I would like to get back a `SmartPtr<B>` object from `doSomething`.

```
SmartPtr<B> b = doSomething(foo);
```

Is it possible ? What kind of casting do I have to do ?
Right now, I just found something I believe ugly :

```
B* b = (B*)doSomething().get()
```

Important notes :  I do not have any access to `SmartPtr` and `doSomething()` code.

Comment: Do you know where the SmartPtr comes from? Any documentation?

Comment: Any smart pointer library worth its salt will provide a specialised cast function to do this. For example in boost with shared_ptr its `boost::shared_ptr<A> b = boost::dynamic_ptr_cast<B>(foo)` Look for something like that.

Comment: Well this is a very basic SmartPtr library and there nothing that allows dynamic casting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of doing that, you can do this :

```
B *b = dynamic_cast< B* >( doSomething.get() );
```

but you have to check if b is NULL.

Comment: It is advised to always use `dynamic_cast` when casting upwards in the class hierarchy and check for `NULL` every time. Unless you can use static cast which means the compiler figures out that you can actually do the cast because the pointer points to a B* object. Keep in mind that `dynamic_cast` requires RTTI which will increase the output file size.

Comment: ... but hand-rolled alternatives to RTTI will also increase the file size. In general, functionality increases file size. The big advantage of the standard RTTI is that it's been tested extensively and optimized.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. But remember, I would like a SmartPtr<B> and not a B*.

Comment: In fact I am using an external library and I cannot modify the SmartPtr implementation. But, you finally answerd my question : I cannot cast from SmartPtr<A> to SmartPtr<B>, even if B is derived from A, if SmartPtr does not give some way to do the cast. Am I right ?

Comment: @Antoine That depends on SmartPtr, but most likely you are right, because SmartPtr should release the object, unless it does something smart.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone stumbling across this decade old question while looking for how to do this, C++11 added `dynamic_pointer_cast`, `static_pointer_cast`, and `const_pointer_cast` to do exactly this.
Now this problem is as simple as

```
shared_ptr<B> b=static_pointer_cast<B>(doSomething(foo));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can define your own SmartPtrCast template function which does something like:

```
template <typename DestT, typename SrcT>
inline SmartPtr<DestT> SmartPtrCast(const SmartPtr<SrcT> &src)
{
    return SmartPtr<DestT>(static_cast<DestT*>(src.get()));
}
```

Then, all you have to do cast gracefully from A to B is:

```
SmartPtr<B> b = SmartPtrCast<B>(doSomething(foo));
```

**Caveat Emptor:**
This will only work if the smart pointer returned by `doSomething()` is referenced somewhere else, and is not destroyed when it goes out of scope. Judging by your example, this is the case, but it's still not as graceful, and it should be noted that the two pointers won't share their reference counting (so if one of them gets destroyed, the second will lose its data).

A better solution is either to detach one of the pointers (if SmartPtr has a detach method). An even better solution (if you don't have a detach method or if you want to share the reference count) is to use a wrapper class:

```
template <typename SrcT, typename DestT>
class CastedSmartPtr
{
private:
    SmartPtr<SrcT> ptr;
public:
    CastedSmartPtr(const SmartPtr<SrcT>& src)
    {
        ptr = src;
    }

    DestT& operator* () const
    {
        return *(static_cast<DestT*> >(ptr.get()));
    }

    DestT* operator->() const
    {
         return static_cast<DestT*> >(ptr.get());
    }

    DestT* get() const
    {
        return static_cast<DestT*> >(ptr.get());
    }
}

template <typename DestT, typename SrcT>
inline SmartPtr<DestT> SmartPtrCast(const SmartPtr<SrcT>& src)
{
    return CastedSmartPtr<SrcT, DestT>(src);
}
```

This will use a `SmartPtr` internally (so reference count is properly shared) and `static_cast` it to internally to `DestT` (with no performance impact). If you want to use `dynamic_cast`, you can do it only once, in the constructor, to avoid unnecessary overhead. You may also want to add additional method to the wrapper such as copy constructor, assignment operator, detach method, etc.

Comment: This will do bad things. You'll end up double destroying the thing pointed to as you wont have both pointers sharing the same reference count. (Yes I''m assuming stuff about the implementation of the SmartPtrs ...)

Comment: Assuming `B* b = (B*)doSomething().get();` or `B *b = dynamic_cast< B* >( doSomething.get() );` works, this should work as just as well, which might not be the best, but if you don't have any access to the smart pointer library, this is the best you can get.

A better still implementation is possible if SmartPtr `detach()` method or something of this sort. I'll factor that in.

Comment: Actually, the question is misformed so your answer looks acceptable.

Comment: Well, on second thought I admit it might be problematic, depending on the circumstances and the SmartPtr implementation (which we don't know a whole lot about). The wrapper solution is much safer, and should not have any performance impact.

Answer (score -2):

```
SmartPtr<B> b = dynamic_cast<B*>(doSomething().get())
```

or perhaps something like `doSomething().dynamic_cast<B*>()` if your SmartPtr supports it.

Comment: -1, this method will cause `b` to have a reference count of 1 (which is generally too low, but just happens to work in this case)

Comment: Why -1? This is the best you can do given the question

Comment: Look at VJo's answer. Since you can't const construct a smart pointer with a proper fererence count, it's far safer to construct a raw pointer. Personally, I'd use a reference, that makes it even clearer that the lifetime is dictated elsewhere.  But Michael Anderson's comment is even more useful - it's solved in any decent smart pointer library.

Comment: I don't agree, you are not answering the original question but changing it.

Comment: This "fix" assumes that doSomething() returns something which has referencecount == 1. If someone else is holding a reference to whatever doSomething() returns, there will be two SmartPtrs referencing the same instance (hence, it will be destroyed twice).