# Cast a polymorphic smart pointer object

Tags: c++, casting, polymorphism, smart-pointers, dynamic-cast

I implemented the following smart pointer template class:

```
#ifndef __ProjectManager__mSharedPtr__
#define __ProjectManager__mSharedPtr__

#include <stdio.h>
#include "RefCount.h"

template <class T>
class mSmartPtr {

    T *data;
    RefCount *rc;

public:

    mSmartPtr(T* srcPtr);
    mSmartPtr(const mSmartPtr&);
    ~mSmartPtr();
    T* operator->() const;
    T& operator*() const;
    mSmartPtr<T>& operator=( mSmartPtr&);
    mSmartPtr<T> operator()(mSmartPtr&);
};

template<class T>
mSmartPtr<T> mSmartPtr<T>::operator()(mSmartPtr<T>& src) {
    return dynamic_cast<??>(src);
}

template <class T>
mSmartPtr<T>::mSmartPtr(T *srcPtr):
data(srcPtr) {
    rc = new RefCount();
    rc->add();
}

template<class T>
mSmartPtr<T>::~mSmartPtr() {
    if (rc->remove() == 0) {
        delete data;
        delete rc;
    }
}


template<class T>
mSmartPtr<T>::mSmartPtr(const mSmartPtr<T> &src):
data(src.data), rc(src.rc) {
    rc->add();
}


template <class T>
T* mSmartPtr<T>::operator->() const {
    return data;
}

template<class T>
T& mSmartPtr<T>::operator*() const {
    return &data;
}

template <class T>
mSmartPtr<T>& mSmartPtr<T>::operator=( mSmartPtr<T> &src) {
    if (this != &src) {
        if (rc->remove() == 0) {
            delete data;
            delete rc;
        }
        data = src.data;
        rc = src.rc;
        rc->add();
    }
    return *this;
}



#endif /* defined(__ProjectManager__mSharedPtr__) */
```

let's say my application contains the following classes:

```
class Base
{
protected:
    ...
public:
    virtual ~Base() =0;
    ...
};


class Derived1 : public Base
{
protected:
    ...
public:
    virtual ~Derived1() {}
    ...
};

class Derived2 : public Base
{
protected:
    ...
public:
    virtual ~Derived2() {}
    ...
};
```

and I need store data at the following way:

```
int int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    std::vector<mSmartPtr<Base>> v;
    mSmartPtr<Derived1> d1 = foo();

    v.push_back(d1);

    return 0;
}
```

I need to fix somehow the cast operator, but how? how do I get the base class in the dynamic cast?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SmartPointer : cast between base and derived classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5633695/smartpointer-cast-between-base-and-derived-classes)

Comment: I tried it before, it's not talking about the cast operator I'm seeking of to get fixed

Comment: Not directly related to the question, but as I've been [told](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28866571/c-multi-index-map-implementation#comment45998667_28866571): names with two leading underscores are reserved for compiler- and standard-library-interal use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783

Comment: Those lines are generated by the Xcode new file component..

Answer (score 0):

In your conversion method extract the underlying pointer and cast it then put it into the new smart pointer. Don't forget to copy the `RefCount` and ensure that your target class has a virtual destructor (so the correct one gets called no matter which smart pointer gets dispossed last).

I couldn't figure out how to define it externally but an inline definition worked.

```
//In the definition, replacing this line
//mSmartPtr<T> operator()(mSmartPtr&)
template<class Tdest>
operator mSmartPtr<Tdest>() {
    mSmartPtr<Tdest> retVal(static_cast<Tdest*>(data));
    retVal.rc = rc;
    retVal.rc.Add();
    return retVal;
}
```

In theory you could also add a version that takes a r-value if you are using C++11 but I think that would take a little work to do correctly so I avoided it.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. How am I allowed to add template parameters to the class method?

Comment: @itorra: I had that thought but dismissed it. I will update the answer to include that bit.

Comment: @itorra: Couldn't figure it out so I defined it inline (probably a good method to inline anyway). Note I also added a separate answer to avoid this entirety.

Answer (score 0):

@Guvante

Your code did not work , I modified it as follows but I don't know if will work well

```
template<class T>
mSmartPtr<T> mSmartPtr<T>::operator ()(mSmartPtr<T>& src) {
    mSmartPtr<T> retVal(dynamic_cast<T*>(src.data));
    retVal.rc = src.rc;
    retVal.rc.Add();
    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: You need another template parameter to define either the input or output type depending on how you implement it. Unfortunately I couldn't figure out how to so redefined mine as inline.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a better alternative to this. Unless you have a different location where you need to be able to do this, you can avoid the headache by changing the way you create the object.

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    std::vector<mSmartPtr<Base>> v;
    mSmartPtr<Base> d1 = static_cast<Base*>(foo());

    v.push_back(d1);

    return 0;
}
```

Just avoid creating an `mSmartPtr` that is typed differently than your vector.